# Problems with cron

Tags: plugin-development, cron, scheduled-posts

I have a this code that delete some post meta at al 7:55 hour of the server:

```
if ( !wp_next_scheduled('borra_meta_datos') ) {
   wp_schedule_event( mktime(7, 55, 0, date('n'), date('j')), 'daily', 'borra_meta_datos' );
}

function borra_todos_los_meta_datos() {
   $args = array(
   'meta_key' => 'destacados',
   'post_status' => 'publish',
   'numberposts' => -1,
   'category' => -14
);
$allposts = get_posts($args);

foreach( $allposts as $postinfo) {
   delete_post_meta($postinfo->ID, 'destacados');
}

$args = array(
   'meta_key' => 'portada',
   'post_status' => 'publish',
   'numberposts' => -1
);
$allposts = get_posts($args);

foreach( $allposts as $postinfo) {
   delete_post_meta($postinfo->ID, 'portada');
}

$args = array(
    'meta_key' => 'slider',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'numberposts' => -1
);
$allposts = get_posts($args);

foreach( $allposts as $postinfo) {
   delete_post_meta($postinfo->ID, 'slider');
}
}
add_action('borra_meta_datos', 'borra_todos_los_meta_datos');
```

All the week the code works fine, but today the code executed early that the hour, i dont know if i am doing something wrong. Additionally i have another code that program all the post of specific user at 3 am of the local hour but today all the posts appear like lost schedule.

```
function programa_post($data, $postarr){
    $hora_de_publicacion = 3;
    if( $data['post_type'] == 'page' ){
        return $data;
    }
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    if($current_user->user_login == 'luis' or $current_user->user_login == 'jorge'){
        $hora_actual = date('H', current_time('timestamp', 0));
        //Forget this if :S
        if($hora_actual >= 3 && $hora_actual <= 23){
            $time_3am = mktime($hora_de_publicacion, 0, 0, date('n'), date('j'));
            $data['post_date'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time_3am);
            $data['post_date_gmt'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time_3am - ( get_option( 'gmt_offset' ) * 3600 ));
        }elseif($hora_actual >= 0 && $hora_actual < 3){
            $time_3am = mktime($hora_de_publicacion, 0, 0, date('n'), date('j'));
            $data['post_date'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time_3am);
            $data['post_date_gmt'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time_3am  - ( get_option( 'gmt_offset' ) * 3600));
        }
    }

    if(trim($data['post_excerpt']) == ""){
        $data['post_excerpt'] = ' ';
        return $data;
    }else{
        return $data;
    }

    return $data;
}
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'programa_post');
```

i dont know if is problem of code or error of cron, i am lost :(